# "Cancel" DatePickerDialog Theme inheritance on Android

Tags: android

I've created an Activity with a DatePickerDialog. I want it to stay with the default system appearance, but when I apply a theme with a background color it mess the DatePickerDialog too. How to avoid that?

My app needs compatibility to android 4.+

That's the theme:

```
<style name="LoginProcess" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
 <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
 <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
 <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
 <item name="buttonStyle">@style/buttonLoginStyle</item>
 <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
 <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/buttonLoginStyle</item>
 <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@android:style/Widget.DatePicker</item>
 <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
 <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
 <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/login_transparent_white</item>
 <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorAccent</item>
 <item name="android:textColorSecondaryInverse">@android:color/white</item>
 <item name="android:radioButtonStyle">@style/radioButtonStyleLogin</item>
</style>
```

And I when some button is clicked this is the code it executes:

```
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(
                            v.getContext(),
                            birthdayDatePickerListener,
                            calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 18,
                            calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                            calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

                    datePickerDialog.show();
```

Thanks in advance